# Is there any way to select an item in a Tkinter Listbox the right click?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to be able to select an item in a Tkinter Listbox using either the left-click or right-click. Is there any way to either bind `"<button-3>"` to some sort of function that selects an item OR invoke a left-click from the right-click when hovering over the Listbox?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: @BryanOakley, I'm not quite sure how to accomplish either.

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation on `bind` to learn how to do bindings in general, then read the documentation on the listbox to see how to select items using code. Everything you need to know is available in the documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

First, use the bind command:

```
self.listBox.bind("<Button-3>", self.rightClick)
```

Then use selection_clear and selection_set with the function nearest to get the index where the cursor is at, then activate it:

```
 def rightClick(self,event):
     self.listBox.selection_clear(0,tk.END)
     self.listBox.selection_set(self.listBox.nearest(event.y))
     self.listBox.activate(self.listBox.nearest(event.y))
```